# How to extend typings in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a library, which has `map` function with these definitions:

```
function map<T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, a: Array<T>): Array<U>
function map<T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, a: Functor<T>): Functor<U>
```

Also, I have another library with `Maybe` type, which extends `Functor`, so it's possible to use it with `map` function above.

Can I extend "library1" `map` function with definition below, so when I use `map` function from "library1" it has 3 overloads(2 above and 1 below)?

```
function map<T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, a: Maybe<T>): Maybe<U>
```

In 1st library, module structure is the following(library typings are generating automatically with `declaration: true` setting):

```
// lib/types/index.d.ts
export interface Functor<T> {
    map: <T1>(fn: (a: T) => T1) => Functor<T1>;
}
export interface MapFunction {
    /**
     * Array
     */
    <T, T1>(f: (x: T) => T1, a: Array<T>): Array<T1>;
    /**
     * Functor
     */
    <T, T1>(f: (x: T) => T1, a: Functor<T>): Functor<T1>;
}
export declare const map: MapFunction;

// lib/index.d.ts
export * from "./lib/types"
```

Next, in `package.json`, I have `"typings": "lib/index.d.ts"`

Comment: 1. Your question has nothing to do with `typings`, please read what that means, 2. Does the implementation support such a signature?

Comment: @NitzanTomer regarding 2, as I correctly understand the question, yes, the implementation supports this signature

Comment: It's not clear to me. If the actual implementation supports such a signature then why don't you include it in the original file? Why do you want to add it later in a different place?

Comment: @NitzanTomer as it's different libraries. First library provides generic `map` function, which works in theory with any data type which has `.map` method(Functor type). 2nd library provides specific `Maybe` data type, which extends from `Functor`, so I want to make it compatible with generic `map` function.

Comment: How about: `map<T, U, S extends Functor>(f: (x: T) => U, a: S<T>): Functor<U>`? If `Maybe` extends `Functor` then this generic signature should match

Comment: @NitzanTomer the thing is, that `Functor` is generic type, it requires an argument when extending it..

Comment: Ok, so: `map<T, U, S extends Functor<T>>(f: (x: T) => U, a: S): Functor<U>`?

Comment: You should be able to add this signature using [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). You haven't included how your modules are structured so it's hard to help more than that.

Comment: Regarding `map<T, U, S extends Functor<T>>(f: (x: T) => U, a: S): Functor<U>` this will not work, as return of map is still `Functor`
Regarding modules structure, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to rename the types you want to extend when you import them:

```
import { Functor, MapFunction as _MapFunction, map as _map } from './lib'
// guessing at './lib', you might have a different project structure

interface Maybe<T> extends Functor<T> {
  map<T1>(f: (x: T) => T1): Maybe<T1>;
}
interface MapFunction extends _MapFunction {
  <T, T1>(f: (x: T) => T1, a: Maybe<T>): Maybe<T1>;
}
const map: MapFunction = _map; // assuming map is implemented generically
```

Hope that helps.